# Not able to set the state while using axios. Promise is returned every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building a Covid-19 tracker and getting data from JSON. I am trying to display the province-wide data by hovering over the map.

Here is the code for fetching the data

```
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchDailyData = async () => {
  try {
    const getData = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/h3");
   console.log(getData.data);
 return (getData.data);
  } catch (error) {console.log(error);}
};
```

Here is the code where map is processed

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ComposableMap, Geographies, Geography } from "react-simple-maps";
import { scaleQuantile } from "d3-scale";
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";
import { fetchDailyData} from "../api/dataprocess";
import LinearGradient from "./LinearGradient.js";
import "./CanadaMap.scss";

/**
 * Courtesy: https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/india.topo.json
 * Looking topojson for other countries/world?
 * Visit: https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps
 */
const CANADA_TOPO_JSON = require("../../../src/canada.topo.json");

const PROJECTION_CONFIG = {
  scale: 100,
  center: [-106.3468, 68.1304] // always in [East Latitude, North Longitude]
};

// Red Variants
const COLOR_RANGE = [
  "#ffedea",
  "#ffcec5",
  "#ffad9f",
  "#ff8a75",
  "#ff5533",
  "#e2492d",
  "#be3d26",
  "#9a311f",
  "#782618"
];

const DEFAULT_COLOR = "#EEE";

// const getRandomInt = () => {
//   return parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
// };

const geographyStyle = {
  default: {
    outline: "none"
  },
  hover: {
    fill: "#ccc",
    transition: "all 250ms",
    outline: "none"
  },
  pressed: {
    outline: "none"
  }
};

// will generate random heatmap data on every call
const getHeatMapData = () => {
  return [
    { id: "MB", state: "Manitoba", value: 2},
    { id: "NB", state: "New Brunswick", value: 2 },
    { id: "AB", state: "Alberta", value: 27 },
    { id: "NF", state: "Newfoundland and Labrador", value: fetchDailyData() },
    { id: "NS", state: "Nova Scotia", value: 1 },
    { id: "SK", state: "Saskatchewan", value: 21 },
    { id: "PE", state: "Prince Edward Island", value: 22 },
    { id: "QC", state: "Quebec", value: 40000 },
    { id: "ON", state: "Ontario", value: 67 },
    { id: "BC", state: "British Columbia", value: 26 },
    { id: "YU", state: "Yukon", value: 27 },
    { id: "NT", state: "Northwest Territories", value: 2 },
    { id: "NU", state: "Nunavut", value: 50 }
  ];
};

function CanadaMap() {
  const [tooltipContent, setTooltipContent] = useState("");
  //const [latest, setLatest] = useState(processedData());

  /**
   * If info in search is empty then i show all the countries
   */
  // const filterCountry =result.filter(item=>{
  //   return searchCountry !== "" ? item.country.includes(searchCountry):item;
  // });

  const [data, setData] = useState(getHeatMapData());

  const gradientData = {
    fromColor: COLOR_RANGE[0],
    toColor: COLOR_RANGE[COLOR_RANGE.length - 1],
    min: 0,
    max: data.reduce((max, item) => (item.value > max ? item.value : max), 0)
  };

  const colorScale = scaleQuantile()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.value))
    .range(COLOR_RANGE);

  const onMouseEnter = (geo, current = { value: "NA" }) => {
    return () => {
      setTooltipContent(`${geo.properties.name}: ${current.value}`);
    };
  };

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    setTooltipContent("");
  };

  const onChangeButtonClick = () => {
    setData(getHeatMapData());

  };

  return (
    <div className="full-width-height container">
      <h1 className="no-margin center">States and UTs</h1>
      <ReactTooltip>{tooltipContent}</ReactTooltip>
      <ComposableMap
        projectionConfig={PROJECTION_CONFIG}
        projection="geoMercator"
        width={600}
        height={220}
        data-tip=""
      >
        <Geographies geography={CANADA_TOPO_JSON}>
          {({ geographies }) =>
            geographies.map(geo => {
              //console.log(geo.id);
              const current = data.find(s => s.id === geo.id);
              return (
                <Geography
                  key={geo.rsmKey}
                  geography={geo}
                  fill={current ? colorScale(current.value) : DEFAULT_COLOR}
                  style={geographyStyle}
                  onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter(geo, current)}
                  onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
                />
              );
            })
          }
        </Geographies>
      </ComposableMap>
      <LinearGradient data={gradientData} />
      <div className="center">
        <button className="mt16" onClick={onChangeButtonClick}>
          Change
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

export default CanadaMap;
```

I am trying to fetch the data through this line

```
{ id: "NF", state: "Newfoundland and Labrador", value: fetchDailyData() },
```

Here is App.js

```
function App() {


  /
  return (
    <div className='Container' >
     <h1 className="title fadeInUp" style={{animationDelay: '0.3s'}}>Canada</h1>

    <CanadaMap />
    </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the map[image: and the error i am getting on hover]

Hovering over the map results in multiple calls to the API [image: like this]

The console.log statement

```
const getData = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/h3");
   console.log(getData.data);
```

gives [image: this result]

I am trying to hover over the map and display the data fetched from the JSON. Is there a way to manage the state properly and store it in a central place so that i can access it(Managing the state in React is quite a new thing for me.) Is it possible to extract the data from the promise and not make multiple calls to the API.

Comment: Put the fetching logic inside a `useEffect` instead of doing like this. Start your `data` with an initial one, empty or predefined, make the fetch in `useEffect` and set your `data` state according to the result.

Comment: @devserkan I wont be able to access the state as it is being called out side the function like this { id: "NF", state: "Newfoundland and Labrador", value: AxiosData() },

I added useffect like this: function CanadaMap() {
  const [tooltipContent, setTooltipContent] = useState("");
  const [AxiosData, setAxiosData] = useState([]);
  //const [latest, setLatest] = useState(processedData());
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      "http://localhost:8080/h3",
    );
 
    setAxiosData(result.data);
  }, []);

Comment: I mean, put those predefined data in your state then.

Answer (score 3):

`fetchDailyData` is **`async` function so it will always return `promise`** :

**Solution :**

To get the direct value you by making function `async` like this :

```
const getHeatMapData = async () => { // <---- HERE
  return [
    { id: "MB", state: "Manitoba", value: 2},
    { id: "NB", state: "New Brunswick", value: 2 },
    { id: "AB", state: "Alberta", value: 27 },
    { id: "NF", state: "Newfoundland and Labrador", value: await fetchDailyData() }, // <--- HERE
    { id: "NS", state: "Nova Scotia", value: 1 },
    { id: "SK", state: "Saskatchewan", value: 21 },
    { id: "PE", state: "Prince Edward Island", value: 22 },
    { id: "QC", state: "Quebec", value: 40000 },
    { id: "ON", state: "Ontario", value: 67 },
    { id: "BC", state: "British Columbia", value: 26 },
    { id: "YU", state: "Yukon", value: 27 },
    { id: "NT", state: "Northwest Territories", value: 2 },
    { id: "NU", state: "Nunavut", value: 50 }
  ];
};
```

Comment: Trying this method triggers another exception :Uncaught TypeError: data.reduce is not a function

    at CanadaMap (CanadaMap.js:90)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)

at line

  max: data.reduce((max, item) => (item.value > max ? item.value : max), 0)